# Why my ListBoxItem style reset on changing content?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I have a listbox with 2 listbox items:

```
<ListBox Name="Monday" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="65.125" Margin="78,45.625,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="139" Style="{DynamicResource monday}" MouseUp="Monday_MouseUp">
    <ListBoxItem Name="MondayLB1" Content="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0" FontSize="20" Height="22" Foreground="White" Focusable="False">
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Февраль" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="White" Focusable="False">
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

When i change listboxitem content in code like this:

```
    listik[tmp].Items[0] = localDateTime.Day.ToString();
```

Style of my listboxitems resets - fontsizes, fontforeground, aligment - turn to default

What I must to do?

Comment: Don't manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. Use DataBinding instead and you will not have these issues.

Comment: u mean set the listboxitem content propetry like this: MainWindow.Monday.Content = "dadasd" ???

Comment: I mean [**Use DataBinding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx). Seems you have a lot of reading to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing procedural code and it's so hard not to reuse any style that you have easily I suggest read more about `DataBinding`. But for the sake of your question, here's what's happening.

The reason why your style of your `listbox` items reset is because you are overriding the actual item which is the `ListBox` and assigning it with just a value of `string` so that output of the listbox will only have the `string` value which doesn't have anything in it which then just converts it into a normal `Textblock` control inside.

```
listik[tmp].Items[0] = localDateTime.Day.ToString();
```

Change it to like this

```
Monday.Items[0] = new ListBoxItem()
            {
                Content = localDateTime.Day.ToString(),
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
                Height= 22,
                Focusable = false
            };
```

Or you can define a `style` for your `listboxitem` then set the new ListBoxItem's style to the newly created style.